# How to resubmit form?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want when I resubmit form it will goes to next page.

But, 
when I am trying to resubmit form it recursively called 
`'$('#payment-form').submit(function(e){}'` function and program goes in infinite loop.
I also try,
`$form.get(0).submit();`

I don't know what exactly this code does but its not working.

What change can I do so that code will work properly.Please Suggest me to find out solution.

**Code:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    // This identifies your website in the createToken call below
    Stripe.setPublishableKey('pk_test_JvzbQnE7YDpeiZOMQO0D9Mar');

    var stripeResponseHandler = function( status , response) {
        var $form = $('#payment-form');

        if (response.error) {
            // Show the errors on the form
            alert("error...!");
            var error = " error : "+response.error.message;
            $form.find('.payment-errors').text(error);
            $form.find('button').prop('disabled', false);
            return false;
        } 
        else 
        {
            alert(" Card Submited..");
            var token = response.id;
            $form.find('.payment-errors').text('Your Card is Submited..! :: ' + token);
            document.getElementById("stripeToken").value = token;

            // and re-submit
           $form.submit();

        }
    };

    jQuery(function($) {
        $('#payment-form').submit(function(e){
        //function submitCard() {
        var $form = $('#payment-form');

        var number = $('.card-number').val();
        var  cvc = $('.card-cvc').val();
        var  exp_month = $('.card-expiry-month').val();
        var exp_year = $('.card-expiry-year').val();
        //var email =$('.card-email').val();
        //var amount =$('.card-amount').val();

        if (!Stripe.validateCardNumber(number)) {
            alert('The credit card number appears to be invalid.');
            return false;
        }

        // Validate the CVC:
        if (!Stripe.validateCVC(cvc)) {
            alert('The CVC number appears to be invalid.');
            return false;
        }

        // Validate the expiration:
         if (!Stripe.validateExpiry(exp_month, exp_year)) {
             alert('The expiration date appears to be invalid.');
             return false;
         }

         //  Disable the submit button to prevent repeated clicks
         $form.find('#submit').prop('disabled', true);

         Stripe.card.createToken({
             number: $('.card-number').val(),
             cvc: $('.card-cvc').val(),
             exp_month: $('.card-expiry-month').val(),
             exp_year: $('.card-expiry-year').val()
         }, stripeResponseHandler);

         //Stripe.card.createToken($form, stripeResponseHandler);

         // Prevent the form from submitting with the default action
         return false;
        });

   });
</script>
```

Comment: What do you mean by __resubmit form__?

Comment: try `$('#payment-form').once('submit', function(e){`

Comment: when I sumbit form$('#payment-form').submit(function(e){

Comment: when I submit form, form is calling "form$('#payment-form').submit(function(e){" function before submission. In this function I am validating card , connect with stripe server, create token and server return token id. I set this id to hidden text field and want to forward this form to next page for further process. but when i submit form it will call same function recursively.

Comment: i tried $('#payment-form').once('submit', function(e){ its not working. Request directly goes to next page without executing function

Comment: You do call back `stripeResponseHandler` in form `submit` which recursive call `form.submit()` again in case of `!response.error`. This loop will never end if response has no errors.

Comment: instead of   $('#payment-form').submit(function(e){   I used   $('#submit').click(function(e){ (submit is id of button). now it stop recursive call but request will not goes to next page.

Comment: I am having same problem, did you figured out the solution for this?